# jQuery according menu script disrupting anchor tag events

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I found a tutorial on css tricks to make a simple accordion.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/

I noticed this is not really based on a navigation, but I could see how it was working so I made some simple adjustments to make it work with a un-ordered list navigation menu. But at the time, even though I got the animation to run sweet, I did not realize this would disrupt the actual anchor click events.

```
var allPanels = $('.sub-menu').hide();

$('li.menu-item a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown();
    return false;
});
```

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yj4px/2/) I have created to demonstrate issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yj4px/2/

As you can see all the links are dead, and the just activate the script.

I would really appreciate any pointers please as I'm stuggling with this one. I would really like to avoid a jquery plugin at all costs. Thanks in advance.

---

At a guess, the script only needs to run `li.menu-item` contains a `ul` - I cannot add classes as the menu will be dynamically generated by a cms, and could change at anytime. So script needs to run by itself.

Comment: issue doesn't make sense, you either use the links for navigation or use them for accordion. If use as link accordion won't open, new page is going to load. To have them open on another page you will need to add a class to active one and run script to open it. Clarfication of overall objective would help a lot

Comment: Indeed, but I still needed the links to work if it had no sub-menu, and the same on the sub-menu links. Removing return false seemed to solve this.

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't even think about when the page reloads if the current menu is open or not. Would be awesome if you know to do this? My class that is added to the active `li.sub-menu-item` is `.current-menu-item` or the parent `li.menu-item` is `.current-menu-parent` - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return false` only if the `<a>` tag is not a direct link or browser will still want to go back to top of page

Change `href` of accordion headers that have panels to "#". Redirect links will work normally with following "IF", accordion will work normally alos

```
$('li.menu-item a').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href')=="#"){
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown();
        return false;
    }
});
```

In your server code add a class "active" to link within panel that needs opening ( match the href to the url)
On page load

```
$('a.active').closest('ul').slideDown()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great step forward. You top adjustment works perfect, and your method for keeping it open when the current is vistited worked a beaut, I adjusted it to this `$('li.current-menu-parent').find('ul').show();` - so it just appears visible on page load. Thank you again!

Comment: you can probably extend the pageload a bit more also... but gets you going.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `return false;` from your function , and it will work great.